# "Error: could not find function "create_matrix" after tm package unpacked

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem when I try to run this code with R :

```
library(RTextTools)
library(e1071)

pos_tweets =  rbind(
  c('I love this car', 'positive'),
  c('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
  c('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
  c('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
  c('He is my best friend', 'positive')
)

neg_tweets = rbind(
  c('I do not like this car', 'negative'),
  c('This view is horrible', 'negative'),
  c('I feel tired this morning', 'negative'),
  c('I am not looking forward to the concert', 'negative'),
  c('He is my enemy', 'negative')
)

test_tweets = rbind(
  c('feel happy this morning', 'positive'),
  c('larry friend', 'positive'),
  c('not like that man', 'negative'),
  c('house not great', 'negative'),
  c('your song annoying', 'negative')
)

tweets = rbind(pos_tweets, neg_tweets, test_tweets)



# build dtm
matrix= create_matrix(tweets[,1], language="english", 
                      removeStopwords=FALSE, removeNumbers=TRUE, 
                      stemWords=FALSE)
```

I get this error !

> `"Error: could not find function "create_matrix`

the code worked fine, before I install the package but I get this error now when I installed tm package.

Any idea please?

Comment: You can make your code a lot easier to read (and write) by avoiding repetitions in your definitions. For instance, define `pos_tweets` as `cbind(c('I love this car', 'This view is amazing', …), 'positive')`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are serious ? you find that my code is not clear?!! strange answer

Comment: No, it's fairly clear. But it could be even clearer: there's still a lot of repetition; not just the values themselves but the syntactic noise around it (repeated `c(…)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to install "slam"

```
#install devtools if you have not installed 
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)

slam_url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/slam_0.1-37.tar.gz"
install_url(slam_url)
```